# Ajax not loading the url file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Whenever the Ajax runs, it says everything works well but as far as I can tell It's not loading the PHP file.

The console has no errors or warning.

Ajax is running the success command

[Demo](https://gyazo.com/ac0f5ad9b653cf87cc1f6160909b7989)

PHP file (download.php)

```
  <script>console.log("Hello?")</script>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['files']) ){
      echo $_POST['files'];
    }

  ?>
```

JS

```
function downloads(){
  files = tickboxes();
  if( isset(files) ){
    $.ajax({
      data: "files=" + files,
      type: "POST",
      url: "./assets/php/download.php",
      success: function(response) {
        console.log("Download Passed Successfully");
      }
    });
  } else {
    alert("Download", "No Files Selected", "red");
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<a onclick="downloads()" id="delete" class='btn btn-default'><image src='./assets/images/download.svg'></image> Download</a>
```

Comment: just change data: `"files=" + files,` to  `"files" : files,`

Comment: @AbanoubMakram — How will that fix the problem?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin in php code i can't see any code except the check for POST so i suggested to change post data format

Comment: "in php code i can't see any code" — I've no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: @AbanoubMakram `unexpected Token :`    So I made it `{"files" : files},` Still doesnt work

@Quentin Yeah I probably should work on security.

Comment: @Nytrix — POST data is user input (which could be specified by a form hosted on a malicious third party site). `echo $_POST['files'];` puts it in an HTML document.

Comment: @Quentin Ok, yes that echo. Never mind me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is successfully loading the PHP file. Having done that, it calls the success function (which you have established runs) and populates the first argument (which you named `response`) with the document.

The only issue with that is that **you never do anything with the value of `response`**. Whatever the content of the document is, you're ignoring it.

Comment: Wow. I hate how Its always the simple things.

Comment: @lesquishy Especially fun when your code actually works.

Comment: Thanks you guys. What a great way to start Ajax.